# How to play .mpeg and .x-wav format audio files in AVPlayer or any other supported controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I am having an audio URL link which I have to download in to a local filePath and play in my app.That audio URL is http://ci.thrymr.net:8082/file/get?fileid=58d0ce23030b28166b322b79 which is a .mpeg format file. Remaining formats like .mp3,.mp4,.m4a,.3gpp are working fine but .mpeg and x-wav audio formats are not playing in AVPlayer in my iOS objective-c Application.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the following Github project or simply use it licence is MIT

https://github.com/Viblast/ios-player-sdk for playing mpeg file.

Audio Playback and Recording Formats

The audio playback formats supported in iOS are the following:

- AAC (AAC-LC)
- HE-AAC (v1 and v2)
- AC-3 (Dolby Digital) - supported since iOS 9.3
- E-AC-3 (Dolby Digital Plus) - supported since iOS 9.3
- MP3 (MPEG-1 audio layer 3
- AMR (Adaptive Multi-Rate, a format for speech) - not supported since
  iOS 4.3
- ALAC (Apple Lossless)
- iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, another format for speech)
- IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
- linear PCM (uncompressed)
- µ-law and a-law

The audio recording formats supported in iOS are the following:
 - AAC (on supported devices only)
 - ALAC (Apple Lossless)
 - iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, for speech)
 - IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
 - linear PCM
 - µ-law and a-law